# Pubsub message of length 148 exceeds maximum of 100 bytes, when considering the payload and attributes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to migrate data with DataFlow GCP. When I read data from BigQuery and try to convert it to PubsubMessage  I am getting  "Pubsub message of length 148 exceeds maximum of 100 bytes, when considering the payload and attributes"

I don't know why I get this and how to resolve the issue. below you can find the snippet:

```
 protected fun executeDataflow(pipeline: Pipeline, query: String, destinationTopic: String) {
    pipeline
            .apply("BigQueryRead", BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
                    .fromQuery(query)
                    .usingStandardSql()
                .withQueryLocation("EU")
            )
            .apply("convert to message",
                ParDo.of(object : DoFn<TableRow, PubsubMessage>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    fun processElement(context: ProcessContext) {
                        val row = context.element()
                        val data = row.toPrettyString().toByteArray()
                        val pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage(data,null)


                        context.output(pubsubMessage)
                    }
                })
            )
            .apply("Pubsub", PubsubIO.writeMessages().to(destinationTopic))

    pipeline.run()
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/27000

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/sdk-version-support-status

You might hit this bug for 2.48.0.

Comment: indeed you are right, I have downgraded to 2.46.0 for now

Comment: I hit the same bug. Looks like at this moment upgrading to 2.50.0 solves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting information by @[XQ Hu](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java/2.49.0) It appears that this is a known issue for the version 2.48.0. for better visibility for the community

> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76647121/pubsub-message-of-length-148-exceeds-maximum-of-100-bytes-when-considering-the#:~:text=github.com/apache/beam/issues/27000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76647121/pubsub-message-of-length-148-exceeds-maximum-of-100-bytes-when-considering-the#:%7E:text=github.com/apache/beam/issues/27000) You might hit this bug for 2.48.0.

This issue is resolved in beam version 2.49.0 which has other security issues ([maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java/2.49.0)) so upgrading to at least 2.50.0 is advised.